# Live feedback from PHP in Symfony

Tags: php, shell, symfony, sh

So I want to be able to get the live feedback from a shell script in a Symfony project. Normally I would do something like (in filename.php):

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php echo getTheStuff(); ?>
  </body>
</html>

<?php

function getTheStuff() {
  while (@ ob_end_flush()); // end all output buffers if any

  $cmd = './test.sh';

  $proc = popen($cmd, 'r');
  echo '<pre>';
  while (!feof($proc))
  {
    echo fread($proc, 4096);
    @ flush();
  }
  echo '</pre>';

  return "OK";
}
```

This code will look to the script file and keep sending through the data as available. This means the browser will show the output of test.sh as it is processed.

Because Symfony uses views to output, it waits until the controller is finished processing before outputting any html. So is there any way I can do this sort of a thing in Symfony?

Comment: Look at these too: [Streaming symfony response from twig template with XMLHttpRequest](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/canq/streaming-symfony-response-from-twig-template-with-xmlhttprequest) and [Streaming console command output from symfony controller](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/stkb/streaming-console-command-output-from-symfony-controller)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YMMV but Symfony includes a [`StreamedResponse`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#streaming-a-response) that might do what you need - you don't necessarily need to return a HTML view. Indeed there are several Response types - `JsonResponse`, `FileResponse` etc.

Note that

> If ob_start() has been called before or the output_buffering php.ini
>   option is enabled, you must call ob_flush() before flush().

I have added this to the code below as this is quite often the case, you may be able to remove the ob_flush() lines and have it still work.

As per the docs linked above:

```php
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse;

// etc.

public function getTheStuffAction(): StreamedResponse 
{   
    $response = new StreamedResponse();
    $response->setCallback(function () {
        var_dump('Hello World');
        ob_flush();
        flush();
        sleep(2);
        var_dump('Hello World');
        ob_flush();
        flush();
    });

    return $response->send();
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Works well, just added an edit for ob_flush(); I had to use this when I did it as I believe one of the default vendor libraries uses ob_start(), so by default this will be required (I checked and I am using output_buffering in php.ini).

Comment: Great, glad to hear it :)

Comment: Not sure why the edit was rejected by @pete and Nigel Ren as it is required to work! You need to add an ob_flush() before every flush() if an ob_start() has been called (which it normally is in Symfony) or the output_buffering php.ini option is enabled.

Comment: I approved your edit - it's your question after all.

Comment: Thankyou, that will help anyone in the future looking to do the same.